# How can we know the number of views a question has outside of the main feed?

Tags: feature-request, views

It seems like the only place to see the number of views a question has is on the question feeds. Is that correct? Is there any way to see the number of views that a question has on the details page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View count is also available in version 1.1 of the API:

> http://api.meta.stackoverflow.com/1.1/questions/116213

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Umm. . .yes?

[image]